# Use element and injected SVG: Gradients not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, sprite-sheet

I am using an svg spritesheet with symbols and inject it inline with SVGInjector. I reference it this way:

```
<svg role="img" width="134px" height="89px">
    <use xlink:href="path/to/sprite.symbol.svg#theid"></use>
</svg>
```

The gradients are declared inside the defs tag of the spritesheet, but they are not showing in Chrome.

I noticed, that it works, if the SVG is not injected. That means, I just placed the whole thing inline into my HTML and the gradients showed as expected. The Spritesheet was exactly the same. The difference is just if it is loaded by JavaScript or not. But the symbol itself is showing. The problem is only the gradient.

This is a simplified version of my spritesheet, with one of the broken icons. In that case, the group called "quadri" is not displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="20.0664" y1="12.1807" x2="20.0664" y2="19.5099">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00774A"/>
        <stop  offset="0.6" style="stop-color:#8CCAAE"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="20.0513" y1="10.627" x2="20.0513" y2="18.8625">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
        <stop  offset="0.3" style="stop-color:#8CCAAE"/>
        <stop  offset="0.55" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8352" style="stop-color:#00774A"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8691" style="stop-color:#007C4E"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9244" style="stop-color:#00895A"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9938" style="stop-color:#009E6E"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00A070"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="21.3755" y1="18.4082" x2="21.3755" y2="13.0789">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00A97C"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="18.0532" y1="18.4072" x2="18.0532" y2="13.0789">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00A97C"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19.1021" y1="18.4072" x2="19.1021" y2="13.0799">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00A97C"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19.9897" y1="18.4082" x2="19.9897" y2="13.079">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#00A97C"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00975F"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 66 33" id="theid">

<g id="Quadri">

    <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" points="23.541,19.298 16.592,19.298 16.592,12.348 23.541,12.348  "/>

    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M23.327,15.869c0,1.455,0.062,2.939,0.062,2.939c0,0.168-0.107,0.275-0.245,0.275h-6.016
        c-0.138,0-0.229-0.122-0.245-0.275c0,0-0.168-1.271-0.168-3.199s0.168-2.847,0.168-2.847c0.016-0.153,0.107-0.275,0.245-0.275
        h6.016c0.138,0,0.245,0.123,0.245,0.275C23.388,12.746,23.327,14.415,23.327,15.869z"/>
    <g>
        <g>

            <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" d="M21.98,14.231c-0.429,0.245-0.551,0.26-1.026,0.551l0.031-0.061
                c0.245-0.26,0.352-0.383,0.505-0.612c-0.428,0.031-1.056,0.077-1.5,0.168l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.031-0.046
                c0.398-0.199,1.163-0.398,1.546-0.444c-0.092-0.138-0.857-0.551-1.041-0.628l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.016-0.046
                c0.582,0.062,1.347,0.337,1.668,0.536c0.138-0.046,0.291-0.046,0.551-0.076c0,0-0.046,0.153-0.322,0.352l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.077,0.184-0.092,1.24-0.245,1.515l0,0l0,0l0,0C22.194,15.012,22.148,14.46,21.98,14.231z"/>

            <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" d="M18.842,17.981l0.015-0.046c-0.229-0.092-0.459-0.153-0.643-0.337l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.061-0.169,0.123-0.291,0.229-0.444l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.015-0.046c-0.199,0.03-0.367,0.107-0.536,0.138l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.138-0.229-0.184-0.551-0.26-0.857
                l-0.015,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.031,0.352-0.046,0.597,0,0.873l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.138,0.046-0.26,0.046-0.383,0.092l-0.015,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.184,0.107,0.321,0.199,0.536,0.291l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.107,0.229,0.229,0.397,0.413,0.581
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0.016-0.046c-0.031-0.138-0.077-0.244-0.062-0.397l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0C18.398,17.936,18.597,17.966,18.842,17.981z"/>

            <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" d="M19.485,14.491c0,0-0.092,0.168-0.168,0.382h-0.015l0,0l0,0c0.536,0.077,1.041,0.291,1.163,0.368
                l-0.015,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.566-0.107-0.857-0.092-1.056-0.077l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.214,0.031-0.245,0.046-0.245,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.123,0.26-0.199,0.689-0.229,0.842l-0.016,0.046l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.107-0.245-0.245-0.735-0.245-0.735l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.275,0.153-0.918,0.75-0.918,0.75l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.352-0.705,0.719-1.026,0.719-1.026l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.122-0.122-0.444-0.184-0.688-0.199l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.015-0.046c0.153-0.046,0.459-0.062,0.658-0.077l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0c0.245,0,0.383,0,0.383,0l0,0l0,0l0,0C19.041,14.66,19.362,14.506,19.485,14.491z"/>

            <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M20.158,17.537c-0.107,0.153-0.214,0.275-0.337,0.413l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.184,0.046-0.398,0.031-0.566,0.031
                l-0.016,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.123,0.061,0.245,0.106,0.383,0.138l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.107,0.092-0.245,0.168-0.352,0.245l-0.015,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.214-0.046,0.505-0.139,0.719-0.276l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.107,0,0.214,0,0.291-0.015l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.016-0.046c-0.016-0.046-0.062-0.077-0.077-0.153l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.199-0.153,0.337-0.291,0.505-0.459l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.03-0.046c-0.168,0.106-0.367,0.275-0.551,0.367l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                C20.174,17.721,20.174,17.645,20.158,17.537z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M22.01,14.185c-0.428,0.245-0.566,0.26-1.025,0.551c0.275-0.291,0.367-0.413,0.536-0.673
                c-0.429,0.015-1.056,0.077-1.5,0.168l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.383-0.214,1.163-0.444,1.562-0.49c-0.092-0.123-0.857-0.536-1.041-0.628l0,0
                l0,0l0,0c0.597,0.046,1.347,0.275,1.699,0.49c0.138-0.046,0.291-0.046,0.551-0.076l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.061,0.107-0.077,0.184-0.321,0.352l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.077,0.184-0.092,1.24-0.245,1.515l0,0l0,0l0,0
                C22.209,14.966,22.179,14.415,22.01,14.185z"/>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M18.873,17.936c-0.245-0.092-0.429-0.199-0.612-0.383l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.061-0.169,0.123-0.291,0.229-0.444l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.199,0.03-0.352,0.046-0.521,0.092l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.138-0.245-0.199-0.49-0.275-0.811l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0c-0.031,0.352-0.046,0.597,0,0.873l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.153,0.046-0.275,0.076-0.398,0.138l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.184,0.107,0.336,0.199,0.536,0.291l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.107,0.229,0.229,0.397,0.413,0.581l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.046-0.152-0.061-0.275-0.03-0.443l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0C18.413,17.89,18.612,17.92,18.873,17.936z"/>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M19.515,14.445L19.515,14.445L19.515,14.445L19.515,14.445L19.515,14.445
                c-0.076,0.107-0.168,0.291-0.184,0.367l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.627,0.092,1.133,0.429,1.133,0.429l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.551-0.107-0.842-0.092-1.056-0.077l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.199,0.015-0.245,0.046-0.245,0.046l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.153,0.321-0.245,0.888-0.245,0.888l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.092-0.245-0.245-0.734-0.245-0.734l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0c-0.275,0.153-0.918,0.75-0.918,0.75l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.352-0.705,0.72-1.026,0.72-1.026l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.123-0.122-0.444-0.184-0.689-0.199l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.123-0.046,0.444-0.107,0.689-0.123l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0c0.245,0,0.382,0,0.382,0l0,0l0,0l0,0C19.071,14.613,19.393,14.46,19.515,14.445z"/>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M20.189,17.491c-0.107,0.153-0.214,0.275-0.337,0.413l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.214,0.062-0.383,0.077-0.597,0.077l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.122,0.061,0.245,0.106,0.382,0.138l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.138,0.122-0.245,0.198-0.382,0.291l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.214-0.047,0.505-0.139,0.719-0.276l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c0.107,0,0.214,0,0.291-0.015l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c-0.015-0.062-0.03-0.107-0.046-0.199l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0c0.199-0.153,0.352-0.291,0.505-0.459l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                c-0.184,0.122-0.337,0.214-0.536,0.306l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
                l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0C20.189,17.675,20.189,17.599,20.189,17.491z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<path d="M25.278,12.936c0.022,0.253,0.033,0.891,0.033,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.033,1.243v0.022H26.4c0.55,0,1.133-0.176,1.133-0.66
    c0-0.308-0.22-0.539-0.638-0.66c0.308-0.077,0.517-0.297,0.517-0.539c0-0.396-0.462-0.55-0.891-0.561h-1.243V12.936z M26.147,13.189
    c0.473,0,0.649,0.099,0.649,0.352c0,0.066-0.022,0.132-0.066,0.176c-0.088,0.11-0.264,0.165-0.495,0.154h-0.011l-0.132,0.341h0.132
    c0.264-0.011,0.484,0.077,0.594,0.22c0.055,0.066,0.077,0.143,0.077,0.22c0,0.264-0.231,0.407-0.693,0.407c-0.077,0-0.209,0-0.286,0
    c-0.022-0.352-0.022-0.836-0.022-0.979c0-0.165,0.011-0.55,0.022-0.869C25.982,13.189,26.07,13.189,26.147,13.189z"/>
<path d="M30.129,12.914h-0.55l0.022,0.605c0.011,0.308,0.022,0.616,0.044,0.913l0,0l0,0c-0.033-0.088-0.066-0.143-0.231-0.385
    c0-0.011-0.572-0.88-0.77-1.133v-0.011h-0.638v0.022c0.022,0.253,0.033,0.891,0.033,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.033,1.243v0.022h0.561
    V15.29c-0.033-0.594-0.033-1.188-0.033-1.76l0,0c0.022,0.066,0.044,0.132,0.132,0.264c0.011,0.011,0.979,1.43,1.034,1.518
    l0.011,0.011h0.451v-0.022c-0.033-0.308-0.033-1.034-0.033-1.243c0-0.231,0.011-0.869,0.033-1.122v-0.022H30.129z"/>
<path d="M30.789,12.936c0.022,0.253,0.033,0.891,0.033,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.033,1.243v0.022h0.671v-0.022
    c-0.022-0.22-0.033-0.649-0.033-0.979c0.033,0,0.121,0.011,0.121,0.011h0.099c0.891,0,1.32-0.242,1.32-0.726
    c0-0.561-0.605-0.693-1.111-0.704H30.8L30.789,12.936z M31.614,13.211c0.319,0,0.539,0.055,0.638,0.187
    c0.044,0.066,0.077,0.132,0.077,0.22c0,0.352-0.396,0.429-0.726,0.429h-0.132c0,0-0.033,0-0.055-0.011c0-0.077,0-0.187,0-0.308
    c0-0.154,0-0.33,0.011-0.495C31.46,13.211,31.537,13.211,31.614,13.211z"/>
<path d="M34.243,12.936c0.022,0.253,0.032,0.891,0.032,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.032,1.243v0.022h0.671v-0.022
    c-0.021-0.22-0.033-0.649-0.033-0.979c0.033,0,0.121,0.011,0.121,0.011h0.1c0.891,0,1.319-0.242,1.319-0.726
    c0-0.561-0.604-0.693-1.11-0.704h-1.057L34.243,12.936z M35.068,13.211c0.318,0,0.539,0.055,0.648,0.187
    c0.045,0.066,0.077,0.132,0.077,0.22c0,0.352-0.396,0.429-0.726,0.429h-0.133c0,0-0.033,0-0.055-0.011c0-0.077,0-0.187,0-0.308
    c0-0.154,0-0.33,0.012-0.495C34.914,13.211,34.991,13.211,35.068,13.211z"/>
<path d="M37.313,12.914L37.313,12.914l-0.012,0.011c-0.121,0.341-0.935,2.101-1.056,2.376l-0.011,0.033h0.582v-0.011
    c0.056-0.165,0.111-0.352,0.188-0.55c0.021,0,0.473-0.011,0.473-0.011h0.396c0,0,0.066,0,0.088,0
    c0.109,0.264,0.188,0.462,0.221,0.561v0.011h0.67l-1.078-2.42h-0.01H37.313z M37.477,13.629c0.056,0.11,0.188,0.44,0.353,0.825
    c-0.022,0-0.056,0-0.056,0h-0.297c0,0-0.308,0-0.352-0.011C37.246,14.146,37.367,13.86,37.477,13.629z"/>
<path d="M39.105,12.936c0.021,0.253,0.033,0.891,0.033,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.033,1.243v0.022h0.67v-0.022
    c-0.032-0.308-0.032-1.034-0.032-1.243c0-0.165,0.011-0.55,0.022-0.847C39.82,13.2,39.896,13.2,39.952,13.2
    c0.319-0.011,0.539,0.055,0.638,0.187c0.044,0.055,0.077,0.132,0.077,0.22c0,0.275-0.265,0.418-0.506,0.429
    c-0.077,0-0.144-0.011-0.144-0.011l-0.043-0.011l0.032,0.044c0.231,0.352,0.595,0.957,0.748,1.243v0.011h0.726l-0.021-0.033
    c-0.021-0.044-0.495-0.737-0.693-1.034c0,0-0.011-0.011-0.011-0.022c0.363-0.11,0.55-0.319,0.55-0.638
    c0-0.561-0.604-0.693-1.111-0.704h-1.055L39.105,12.936z"/>
<path d="M42.416,12.914h-0.648v0.022c0.021,0.253,0.032,0.891,0.032,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.032,1.243v0.022h0.67v-0.022
    c-0.033-0.308-0.033-1.034-0.033-1.243c0-0.231,0.012-0.869,0.033-1.122v-0.022H42.416z"/>
<path d="M43.043,12.936c0.021,0.253,0.033,0.891,0.033,1.122c0,0.209,0,0.935-0.033,1.243v0.022h1.122
    c0.55,0,1.133-0.176,1.133-0.66c0-0.308-0.22-0.539-0.638-0.66c0.308-0.077,0.518-0.297,0.518-0.539c0-0.396-0.463-0.55-0.892-0.561
    h-1.243V12.936z M43.912,13.189L43.912,13.189c0.473,0,0.648,0.099,0.648,0.352c0,0.066-0.021,0.132-0.065,0.176
    c-0.088,0.11-0.265,0.165-0.495,0.154h-0.012l-0.131,0.341h0.131c0.265-0.011,0.484,0.077,0.595,0.22
    c0.056,0.066,0.077,0.143,0.077,0.22c0,0.264-0.23,0.407-0.693,0.407c-0.076,0-0.209,0-0.285,0
    c-0.012-0.352-0.022-0.836-0.022-0.979c0-0.165,0.011-0.55,0.022-0.869C43.747,13.189,43.835,13.189,43.912,13.189z"/>
<path d="M46.959,12.914h-0.451v0.011c-0.132,0.363-0.99,2.222-1.056,2.376l-0.011,0.033h0.582v-0.011
    c0.056-0.165,0.11-0.352,0.188-0.55c0.021,0,0.473-0.011,0.473-0.011l0.396,0.011c0,0,0.066,0,0.088,0
    c0.1,0.264,0.176,0.462,0.221,0.561v0.011h0.67L46.959,12.914L46.959,12.914z M46.684,13.629c0.055,0.11,0.188,0.44,0.353,0.814
    c-0.022,0-0.056,0-0.056,0h-0.297c0,0-0.308-0.011-0.352-0.011C46.453,14.135,46.574,13.86,46.684,13.629z"/>
<path d="M48.234,13.541c0,0.429,0.43,0.594,0.804,0.748c0.297,0.121,0.594,0.242,0.594,0.44c0,0.066-0.011,0.11-0.044,0.154
    c-0.066,0.088-0.209,0.121-0.439,0.11c-0.221-0.011-0.474-0.088-0.76-0.209l-0.121-0.055v0.099v0.44l0.078,0.022l0.043,0.011
    c0.143,0.033,0.407,0.099,0.682,0.099c0.716,0,1.134-0.286,1.134-0.748c0-0.44-0.44-0.616-0.825-0.77
    c-0.286-0.11-0.583-0.231-0.583-0.418c0-0.055,0-0.22,0.363-0.22c0.274,0,0.538,0.11,0.682,0.176l0.144,0.055v-0.088v-0.44
    l-0.133-0.022c-0.131-0.022-0.363-0.066-0.604-0.066C48.643,12.826,48.234,13.112,48.234,13.541z"/>
<path d="M26.323,16.379c0.506,0,1.1,0.143,1.1,0.693c0,0.308-0.176,0.517-0.539,0.627c0.055,0.099,0.627,0.979,0.726,1.066h-0.715
    c-0.154-0.297-0.517-0.902-0.77-1.287c0.044,0.012,0.11,0.012,0.187,0.012c0.209,0,0.506-0.154,0.506-0.43
    c0-0.34-0.418-0.407-0.627-0.407c-0.11,0-0.209,0.011-0.264,0.011c-0.011,0.297-0.022,0.671-0.022,0.836
    c0,0.209,0,0.913,0.033,1.254h-0.66c0.033-0.33,0.044-0.759,0.044-1.254c0-0.418,0-0.913-0.033-1.133h1.034V16.379z"/>
<path d="M29.766,16.379v0.352c-0.33-0.033-0.66-0.033-1.001-0.033c-0.088,0-0.165,0-0.286,0.011
    c-0.011,0.22-0.011,0.495-0.011,0.682l0.869-0.021v0.363l-0.88-0.022c0,0.209,0.011,0.506,0.022,0.759
    c0.451-0.011,0.902-0.011,1.342-0.033v0.342H27.83c0.033-0.33,0.033-1.045,0.033-1.254c0-0.231-0.011-0.87-0.033-1.145H29.766z"/>
<path d="M31.548,16.379c0.088,0.242,0.88,1.991,1.067,2.387h-0.66c-0.033-0.109-0.121-0.308-0.22-0.561
    c-0.132,0-0.275-0.012-0.473-0.012c-0.176,0-0.319,0-0.473,0.012c-0.077,0.197-0.132,0.385-0.187,0.561H30.03
    c0.132-0.297,0.935-2.035,1.067-2.387H31.548z M31.603,17.887c-0.154-0.375-0.297-0.693-0.341-0.814
    c-0.11,0.23-0.231,0.506-0.352,0.814c0.099,0,0.242,0.01,0.352,0.01C31.372,17.896,31.482,17.896,31.603,17.887z"/>
<path d="M34.684,18.766h-1.871c0.033-0.33,0.033-1.045,0.033-1.254c0-0.23-0.011-0.869-0.033-1.144h0.66
    c-0.022,0.275-0.033,0.901-0.033,1.144c0,0.154,0,0.605,0.011,0.946h0.352c0.363,0,0.627-0.022,0.881-0.044V18.766z"/>
<path d="M37.73,16.379v0.352c-0.33-0.033-0.66-0.033-1.002-0.033c-0.088,0-0.164,0-0.285,0.011c-0.012,0.22-0.012,0.495-0.012,0.682
    l0.869-0.021v0.363l-0.88-0.022c0,0.209,0.011,0.506,0.022,0.759c0.451-0.011,0.902-0.011,1.342-0.033v0.342h-1.991
    c0.033-0.33,0.033-1.045,0.033-1.254c0-0.231-0.011-0.87-0.033-1.145H37.73z"/>
<path d="M39.139,16.335c0.297,0,0.561,0.044,0.736,0.088v0.528c-0.209-0.121-0.43-0.22-0.814-0.22c-0.34,0-0.363,0.121-0.363,0.22
    c0,0.429,1.387,0.374,1.387,1.133c0,0.473-0.418,0.748-1.122,0.748c-0.319,0-0.604-0.055-0.792-0.121v-0.518
    c0.43,0.199,0.693,0.275,0.936,0.275c0.274,0,0.406-0.076,0.406-0.253c0-0.473-1.386-0.396-1.386-1.198
    C38.137,16.566,38.533,16.335,39.139,16.335z"/>
<path d="M42.383,16.379v0.352c-0.318-0.033-0.418-0.044-0.781-0.044c-0.011,0.286-0.011,0.67-0.011,0.836
    c0,0.209,0,0.924,0.033,1.254h-0.671c0.033-0.33,0.044-1.045,0.044-1.254c0-0.166-0.011-0.55-0.022-0.836
    c-0.363,0.011-0.461,0.011-0.781,0.044v-0.352H42.383z"/>
<path d="M43.67,16.379c0.088,0.242,0.88,1.991,1.066,2.387h-0.659c-0.033-0.109-0.121-0.308-0.22-0.561
    c-0.133,0-0.275-0.012-0.474-0.012c-0.176,0-0.319,0-0.473,0.012c-0.077,0.197-0.132,0.385-0.187,0.561h-0.572
    c0.132-0.297,0.935-2.035,1.066-2.387H43.67z M43.725,17.887c-0.154-0.375-0.297-0.693-0.341-0.814
    c-0.11,0.23-0.231,0.506-0.353,0.814c0.1,0,0.242,0.01,0.353,0.01S43.615,17.896,43.725,17.887z"/>
<path d="M46.673,16.379v0.352c-0.319-0.033-0.418-0.044-0.78-0.044c-0.012,0.286-0.012,0.67-0.012,0.836
    c0,0.209,0,0.924,0.033,1.254h-0.671c0.032-0.33,0.044-1.045,0.044-1.254c0-0.166-0.012-0.55-0.021-0.836
    c-0.363,0.011-0.463,0.011-0.781,0.044v-0.352H46.673z"/>
<path d="M48.961,16.379v0.352c-0.33-0.033-0.66-0.033-1.001-0.033c-0.088,0-0.165,0-0.286,0.011
    c-0.011,0.22-0.011,0.495-0.011,0.682l0.868-0.021v0.363l-0.879-0.022c0,0.209,0.011,0.506,0.021,0.759
    c0.451-0.011,0.902-0.011,1.342-0.033v0.342h-1.99c0.033-0.33,0.033-1.045,0.033-1.254c0-0.231-0.012-0.87-0.033-1.145H48.961z"/>

</symbol>
</svg>
```

Edit: Clearified my question and updated it to my knowledge.

Comment: There's a Firefox bug that causes gradients not to work if they are the children of symbols. There's an easy workaround though, fix the generation so the gradients aren't children of symbols.

Comment: As I wanted to try that out, I noticed, that in Chrome both versions do not work.

Comment: Chrome has problems with relative URLs and external documents. You might need to make the URLs absolute to get them to work there.

Comment: They are. What I meant is: Chrome displays both svgs without the group "quadri".

Comment: No, they are **not**. url(#SVGID_6_) is a relative URL.

Comment: Oh. I understood you wrong. Now I have an interesting result: With absolute urls (path/to/file.svg#SVGID_6_) both svgs, that means even the symbol display correctly in firefox, but in Chrome it is still the same.